# CrudRepository in Spring JPA Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I was trying to understand use of `JPA Repository` in Spring Boot.

I was able to execute the list operation with following DAO

```
@Repository
public interface CountryManipulationDAO extends CrudRepository<CountryEntity, Long>{

    @Query("Select a from CountryEntity a")
    public List<CountryEntity> listCountries();
```

Since, `CountryEntity` have primary key as `char`. I was confused about use of `Long` in DAO class

Thanks

Comment: Change CrudRepository<CountryEntity, Long> to CrudRepository<CountryEntity, Character>. 2nd parameter in CrudRepository template refer to the id's type

Comment: I want to know the use of `Long`. Change it to `Character` doesn't expand my knowledge

Comment: Most likely you only will run into an issue when using an operation that uses the generic type of ID like `findOne(ID)`, `exists(ID)` or `delete(ID)`

Comment: Thanks @NicoVanBelle, that means `Long` represents primary key for DTO ?

Comment: @Ankit Correct. Check the interface: `Interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>`

Comment: You do not need a `@Repository` annotation when extending `CrudRepository` or any of the other premade Spring Data repository interfaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Repository` interface in spring-data takes two generic type parameters; the domain class to manage as well as the id type of the domain class.

So the second type parameter represents the type of the primary key.

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {
    <S extends T> S save(S entity);
    T findOne(ID primaryKey);
    Iterable<T> findAll();
    Long count();
    void delete(T entity);                                                                                                 
    boolean exists(ID primaryKey);      
}
```

When you call a function that does not use the id of the entity, no type matching will be done and you will not run into issues. Such as in your case.

On the other hand, you will run into issues when using the operations that use the id like `findOne(ID)`, `exists(ID)`, `delete(ID)` and `findAll(Iterable<ID>)`.

For more information on Repositories, check the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html).